# Jms dependency not resolved?

Tags: java, docker, gradle

Hi I have created one docker-compose.yml file as bellow configuration

```
version: '3'
services:
  activemq:
    image: webcenter/activemq:latest
    ports:
      - 8161:8161
      - 61616:61616
      - 61613:61613
    environment:
      ACTIVEMQ_NAME: amq
      ACTIVEMQ_REMOVE_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT: 'True'
      ACTIVEMQ_ADMIN_LOGIN: admin
      ACTIVEMQ_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    volumes:
      - /container_data/activemq/data:/data/activemq
      - /container_data/activemq/log:/var/log/activemq
```

I have gradle configuration as following:

```
task startDocker(type: Exec) {
    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'docker-compose', '-f', './docker-compose.yml', 'up', '-d'
    } else {
        commandLine 'docker-compose', '-f', './docker-compose.yml', 'up', '-d'
    }
}

jar  {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File Example',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class': 'com.jms.MyServer'
    }
}
```

when i am running my java application independently it runs fine as
i am using configuration from following command:

```
docker container inspect <container-id>
```

but when i run *jar* file it's not able find classes of *jms*

following is an error i'm getting when i ran using jar

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/Destination
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
```

How could i run jar file and resolve this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have jms dependencies which are not packed inside your jar so it can't be run as a standalone.

If you want to pack your dependencies inside your jar you can use something like [shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) or [one-jar](https://github.com/rholder/gradle-one-jar) or its also not to difficult to hand roll your own solution.

Another option is to use the [application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) to create a zip or a tar containing

1. your jar
2. the dependency jars
3. a startup script

Comment: thanks lance-java i have applied your suggestion it works for me. but, i a'm getting another error of broker url after packed in jar,

as i have modified my question

Comment: Don't modify your question. If this answered your question, mark it as the solution then ask another question. This way someone else can find your it in future